# Domain name point to subdomain of a entire different domain

Tags: dns, subdomain, masking

I am completely confused the last few days with this and I still haven't found an outcome that's worked.

Basically I have a domain name without hosting at letshost.ie which is dublinplasterer.ie

I also Have one domain & hosting with godaddy for domain-  shanafagan.com which is my own site for web/graphic design service.

I created a subdomain=  dublinplasterer.shanafagan.com  and uploaded the site files.

Basically I want for example when someone types in dublinplasterer.ie in the address bar if goes to dublinplasterer.shanafagan.com but doesn't show dublinplasterer.shanafagan.com url, stays as dublinplasterer.ie

Im not even sure if this can be done at this stage. head is melted

shanafagan.com and the subdomain dublinplasterer.shanafagan.com have the same ip so how will that work if changing dns?

Any help would be greatly appreciated , am so stuck at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do it this way you would need a web server for domain2.com

Search for ProxyPass.

The way you should do this is add a second domain on your web hosting (cpanel for example) and point the other domain to this web server.

If you are struggling I recommend using a solution like cPanel that is widely used and simplifies much of the process. It is common enough you can google most issues.

Answer (score 0):

So normally you would have started by making an add-on domain (instead of a subdomain) which would also create it's own subdomain anyway. To do that, you go to your cPanel in GoDaddy and find add-on domain, then make it "dublinplasterer.ie" (Don't add www. to it. Even though this name is hosted elsewhere, we will later go to your DNS files at that hosting and point it to your GoDaddy's name servers and this add-on helps it direct to the right root folder) then choose your local root folder for that site (I think you can actually make this the same as your other subfolder already hosting your files and then it will just pull the same site) or you can pick a different subfolder and then make the add-on domain. This tells any request to this name server that if it is a request for "dublinplasterer.ie" it needs to send it to the subfolder you specified.

If you don't make the subfolder the same as the one you already made, you can either load the same content into your new subfolder or create a CNAME record telling this add-on to point to your subfolder instead  but that is more complex so go with the other route.

Lastly, you need to go to your original hosting at letshost.ie and under your domain name find the DNS records tab. Change the name servers to match your GoDaddy ones and now (may take a day or two to show as DNS changes often take days and can't be seen immediately but you can try using a different device/computer/mobile that hasn't loaded it previously to see if it will refresh the correct dns) it should work. Even though it points to your main site name servers, the add-on domain you made receives it and directs it to the subfolder you specified on the add-on domain.

Hope that helps, let me know if it works for you.